# Displaying Text on top of a media9 \includemedia display (3UD model)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-node, media9, rendering

Is it possible to display text (also tables, images, etc) on top of a media9 U3D model? I have tried the using a tikz node, as you would with images, but I simply get:

[image]

whereas what I would like is:

[image]

My code is

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\FILENAME}{Stanley-Screwdriver-obj}

    \centering

    \includemedia[label=\FILENAME.u3d,
    width=0.999\paperwidth,
    height=0.999\paperheight,
    activate=pageopen,
    3Droll=-123.73760579654027,
    3Dc2c=0.4816674292087555 -0.8381012082099915 -0.25609147548675537,
    3Dcoo=9.719682693481445 15.044689178466797 -1.3384838104248047,
    3Droo=255.14380473106124,
    transparent=true,
    3Dtoolbar=true,
    3Dlights=Headlamp]{}{\FILENAME.u3d}

    \vspace*{-25em}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
        \node [rotate=45,scale=30,text opacity=0.2] at (current page.center) {Example};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The manual states "media artwork is drawn over an opaque background prior to composition *over the page content*" (and option `transparent` will make that background transparent). Whether *over the page content* is a limitation of PDF or how `media9` puts the object into the PDF it doesn't say.